# Setting a var equal to a number in an array minus percent times another percent

Tags: javascript

I have an algo that is essentially =1-(1-50%)*(1-24%)

the 50% is the probability and the 24% is the unresolved amount.

1 is the starting position of an array - (1-50%) or .5 * (1-24%) or .76. The answer comes out to .62 which I run the value through an array and match the next closest value to 62%.

What I want to know is how in javascript do you write 1-(1-50%)*(1-24%) and have it give you a value. Right now is returns NaN.

Any help is much appreciated.

I have created this algo in excel and it works great but need to figure out how to write this in javascript.

Here is a fiddle of what I am trying to do

```
var colicEnd = 1 - (1 - probability50) * (1 - unknown);

http://jsfiddle.net/jessemfulton/ar4sufaj/4/
```

Right now the script runs through and takes the value of the second dropdown and minuses it from the first to get a number. I then take that number and run it through an array to get the unknown value. The next part I want to create a probability for 50% So I would take the first possibility of the array which is 1 and minus the value of 50% or .5 and then times it by the unknown value to get the percentage which is this 1-(1-50%)*(1-24%).

So in the fiddle if you select 2 from the first dropdown and 6 from the second you are left over with 4. Take that number and run it through the wessel_array to give you a value of 23.6% so I round up to 24%. I then need to take that value and add it the the algo above to get the 50% probability the colic will end in 7 weeks because the left over remainder of the algo above is 62% which I then have to go up to the next available number in the wessel_data and you get the week that is assigned to 64% which is 7.

Comment: What is the actual question? Which code produces `NaN`? `1-(1-50%)*(1-24%)` is a syntax error.

Comment: "50%" = 50/100 = 0.5

Comment: In many coding languages, `%` means _modulo_ or _"remainder"_. i.e. `5 % 4` is `1` because `5` is `4n + 1`

Answer (score 0):

The percentages need to be expressed as decimals.

```
var result = 1 - (1 - .5) * (1 - .24);
```

[Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5xnca5ov/) with your example.

Comment: I have added a fiddle so you can see the actual project. The code I have is                                                          var colicEnd = 1 - (1 - probability50) * (1 - unknown);              I am trying to use arrays and variables as the percentages.

Comment: It seems as if I am getting an error on the unknown value as its returning 24% not .24. Anyone know how to change 24% to .24?